# I have a 3D dataset of coordinates x,y,z. How do I check if the dataset is normally distributed?

Tags: python, multidimensional-array

The dataset is large with over 15000 rows.

One row of x,y,z plots a point on a 3D plot.

I need to scale the data and so far I'm using RobustScaler(), but I want to make sure that the dataset is either normally distributed or it isn't.

Comment: Does this help ? https://www.statology.org/multivariate-normality-test-python/

Answer (score 0):

Matplotlib histogram [plt.hist()] can be used for checking data distribution. If the highest peak middle of the graph, then datasets are normally distributed.

Comment: It doesnt work for 3d data tho. Am I wrong?

Comment: If you think each x, y and z-axis is an independent data column, then the 1d histogram san used.  Let's assume any of them (x,y,z) do not follow the normal distribution, then combine also not follow the normal distribution.